# django 1.7 makemigrations on existed table

Tags: django, django-migrations

I want to use Django 1.7 for a new project.
and I already have database with many records.

In many Django tutorials, 
it demo how to use migration system from a fresh new project.

In my case, use django-admin startapp `todo`
and will use a existed table named `notesnote`.
I use inspectdb to dump `notesnote` class and write it into `todo/models.py`

```
class NotesNote(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    authors = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

and then

```
python manage.py makemigrations todo
```

to generate `todo/migrations/0001_initial.py`
then

```
python manage.py migrate --fake todo
```

do a fake migrate(cause the table already existed).

Then, If I want to amend the table's field, say add a "category" field

```
category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Then generate the 0002 migration diff by:

```
python manage.py makemigrations todo
```

However, when I do the migrate by

```
python manage.py migrate todo
```

I got error as below:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: todo_notesnote

Seems it add the app's name in front of the existed table.
Which steps should I do to make a usable migrations for existed table?

Comment: oops, I think maybe I am wrong in the beginning, I supposed "NotesNote" already existed, so use "--fake"

Comment: Did you read the documentation about [integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/legacy-databases/)? There you can find some useful advices: in particular you should add a *db_table = 'NotesNote'* option to the inner Meta class of your model.

Comment: @Baxeico, Thanks a lot, I never know the doc, Let's me study for a while :)

Comment: @baxeico after reading the doc, it works, thanks a lot. although I don't know how to mark it as resolved :(

Comment: I added my comment as an answer, reading the [etiquette](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette) I'd probably have added it as an anwser from the beginning. If you found it useful you can mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation about [integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/legacy-databases/) contains some useful advices for your use case: in particular you should add a *db_table = 'notesnote'* option to the inner *Meta* class of your model.